# prepend the next read in line with information from the previous read in line

Tags: postgresql, perl

Development Platform: Ubuntu 17.10 mainly command line work

Tools: perl 5.26 and postgresql 9.6

goal: Convert a file so I can \COPY it into postgresql

Information: Line delimiter is the # sign

Database table columns: `id work composer artist conductor orchestra album_title`

problem: append next info line to current id line

In the following how do I preserve the 'mmfmm01#' so upon the next line iteration I can prepend it to that next line? As this is my first post please let me know if the code example is too much or too little.

I am going from this:

> Le Nozze di Figaro, K. 492 / The Marriage of Figaro: Le Nozze di
>   Figaro, K. 492 / The Marriage of Figaro: Cinque ... dieci ... venti /
>   Five ...Ten ...Twenty

Eventually to this:

> mfmm01#Cinque dieci venti#Mozart####Entertaining Made Simple Merlot,
>   Filet Mignon, Mozart

After running the script I have the following:

> mfmm01#

How do I have to preserve the 'mfmm01#' so upon the next line iteration I can prepend it to that next line?

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl 
    # use clauses for File, cwd, etc#
    # usage statment

    # Variables - append _orig to input_file
    my $id = $ARGV[1];
    my $input_file = $ARGV[0];
    my $album_title = $ARGV[2];
    my $output_file = output_file;
    my $input_file_orig = $input_file;
    $input_file_orig = $input_file_orig .= _orig;

    ##############################################
    # Ensure that the provided input file exists #
    ##############################################

    ##########################################################
    # Read all file lines into an array                      #
    ##########################################################

   ###########################################################
   # Modify each line to meet the following specs:           #
   # id#work#composer#artist#conductor#orchestra#album_title #
   ###########################################################
     for my $line (@lines) {
        $line =~ s/[\n\r\t]+//g;
        ######################################################
        # Ignore lines with num:num, lines that begin with $ #
        # and emptry string lines                            #
        # ####################################################
        if ( $line =~ /[0-9]:/m ) {
            next;
        } elsif ( $line =~ /^\$/m ) {
            next;
        } else {
        if ( $line =~ /^\s*$/m ) {
                next;
        }
        }
        ########################################################
        # If line is a number followed by a space, prepend id  #
        # and replace space with the # character               #
        ########################################################
        if ( $line =~ /^\d\d\s/m ) {
            $id_num = $line;
            $id_num =~ s/(\d\d)\s/$id$1#/g; 
        } else {
            if ( $line =~ /^\d\s/m ) {
            $id_num = $line;
            $id_num =~ s/(\d)\s/$id$1#/g;
   #        print ("\$line after removing space: \"$line\"\n");
        }
    }
    ####################################################
    # If line begins with an alphabetic character then #
    # prepend id_num and append album_title            #
    ####################################################
    if ( $line =~ /Sold/m ) {
        next;
    }
    if ( $line =~ /^[A-Z]/m ) {
        ################################################i##
    # At this point $line exists but $id_num is empty #
    # I thought $id_num would live through the next   #
    # line read                                       #
    ###################################################
           $prepend_line =~ s/($line)/$id_num$1/g; 
           print("$prepend_line");
           $append_line =~ s/($prepend_line)/$1#Mozart###$album_title/g;
           open my $ofh, '>>', $output_file or die $!;
           print $ofh "$append_line\n";
           close $ofh or die $!;
           print("\$append_line: $append_line\n");
        }
    }

    1;
```

Comment: can you edit your post to give more clear examples of the input and desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I will fix this by capturing the value to a file. Upon the next line read I will extract the value and prepend it to the string. Thank you for looking at this. I don't know why I didn't think of this before.

Thank you;

Sherman